# MySQL query takes a while, need to optimize if possible

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query to fetch a user's contacts list.

```
SELECT contacts.contactID as id, contacts.conversationID, users.username,
profile_picture, picture_path, full_name, sex, availabilityStatus
FROM contacts
JOIN users ON contacts.contactID = users.id
WHERE contacts.ownerID = ?;
```

Any idea on how I can optimize this query?

The `users` table has about 1M rows.
The `contacts` has about 10M rows.

There are indexes on the user id, contactID, ownerID

On someone who has for example 200 contacts, the query takes a few seconds.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried?  We would need a lot more information on this to determine an answer.  Is contacts or users a smaller table?  Are contactID and id indexed?

Comment: standard rule of thumb: any field(s) used in a decision context (e.g. where, order by, join, case, etc...) should have an index on them.

Comment: Being that the code is currently working, does this not belong on code review?

Comment: Table definitions and EXPLAIN.

Comment: How large are your tables?

Comment: Also does this query really needs optimizing?What is the running time?

Comment: It's a few seconds on someone who has about ~ 200 contacts, also edited post for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Use indexes on contacts.contactID, users.id and contacts.ownerID columns.